# Text Area helper , how to set maxlength

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, textarea

Text Area helper , how i set the maximum length of string to 100.
Is there is any max length attribute in text-area helper in ROR.

Code will help me.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

By default at the View level rails doesn't provide the character limit for text area . You can explictly  use Javascript function which limits the Number of the Characters entered with `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` events in your view and place the function in `public/javascript/application.js` .

[Here is a nice tutorial for character limit within text area](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html) .

Hope it is useful !

Comment: The W3C HTML spec doesn't provide a property to limit a `textarea` to a maximum number of characters either. You need to use javascript to achieve this, regardless of your framework.

Answer (score 2):

in textarea there aren't lengths, you can set columns and rows, so you can have a textarea widht of '100 columns' but it doesn't mean that it will accept only 100 chars.